# Does the improper integral converge?

Tags: calculus

I tried comparing it with 1/(x-2)^2 but didn't worked
$$
\int_2^{\infty} \left( \frac{x}{x^3 + \sqrt{x}-1} \right) \,\text{d}x
$$

Comment: is that $\sqrt x - 1$ (written as `$\sqrt{x}$` or is it $\sqrt{x-1}$ (written as `$\sqrt{x-1}`)?

Comment: @5xum in either case, that expression is positive on the given interval. So the denominator is $\ge x^3$, whence the whole expression is $\le \frac{x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{x^2}$, and the comparison works from there.

Comment: I edited, thanks for pointing that out